# Testar valor de saída para conferir se é INTEIRO

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, portugol, visualg

Montei a função abaixo, para verificar se o valor de saida é integer ou real.

```
 funcao menu_8():inteiro
    var
    logaritmo :real
    inicio
    para contador de 0 ate 12 faca
          logaritmo <- ((log(i[contador])) / (log(2)))
          se ((logaritmo % 2 = 0) OU (logaritmo % 2 = 1)) entao
             escreva(" é Potencia de 2: ", i[contador])
          fimse
    fimpara
    escreval(" ")
    fimfuncao
```

Caso ela seja real, não deve exibir nada na tela.

Caso seja integer, deve exibir uma mensagem "`é potencia de 2`"

Como testar se LOGARITMO é INTEIRO?

Comment: seria que se for inteiro entao ele exibe na tela a mensagem caso contrario nao exibe pois o numero nao é potencia de dois.

Comment: por isso o topico esta com o nome Testar valor de saída para conferir se é INTEIRO se o teste = int entao imprime mensagem caso contrario nao faz nada!

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não é possível fazer MOD(%) em números reais, caso isso seja possível seu algoritmo já faz isso, pois caso ele seja real ele retornaria um valor real como resultado do MOD  e não passaria na condição do SE.

Answer (score 1):

Use a função `int` para truncar o valor. Se o valor original for igual ao truncado, é inteiro.

```
SE logaritmo = int(logatimo) ENTAO
```